# Obtain Static IP set in DHCP on Cisco ASA

Tags: ipv4, cisco-asa, dhcp

I am working with an ASA-5505.  I am trying to set aside a set of 10 IP addresses.   Currently I have internally 10.1.10.100 - 254 set for my current vlan -- `vlan 1`, and all equipment attached is receiving it's IP via dhcp from the ASA.   I would like to reserve the group `10.1.10.200 through .210` for static IPs ..  For servers, equipment and whatnot.  Is it possible to to this on the ASA?  Would I have to set up a separated vlan on it's own switch?  I have googled and googled, however I cannot piece together exactly what I am asking.  Is it possible to reserve these IP's from the dhcp so they don't get leased out and possibly change/conflict with other appliances on the network?  Any help appreciated from this networking noob..

Comment: Ricky Beam answered the question, but as a side note you might consider moving your reserved block outside the DHCP scope. If you can, it's best to allocate your biggest block of addresses together in one contiguous space, then your next biggest block, and so on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ASA does not have a means of excluding addresses (or adding reservations.) The only option is to use addresses outside the DHCP scope (i.e. adjust the range to not include your statics.)

[This](http://ccie-or-null.net/2013/02/06/dhcp-reservations-on-a-cisco-asa-5505-maybe/) suggests a static arp entry may steer dhcp assignments, but a) it's not a documented/supported feature, and b) others report it not working.

Answer (score 0):

The ip address can not be reserved but they can be excluded from the dhcp pool which has been defined in a network. excluded ip addresses can be used for a particular nework device in the same subnet.